# EOF operator in Shell not exiting

Tags: ruby, shell, hadoop, vagrant, eof

I am trying to edit hadoop file on my guest machine using Vagrantfile. I am using `cat`. This edites the file but even EOF is considered as text and it has been inserted in the file `/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml`. EOF is not exiting and hence everything below is being considered as part of the text.

What change should I make on this code?

```
      if node.vm.hostname == "node1"
        node.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        cat >/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml <<EOF
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
          <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>fs.default.name</name>
              <value>hdfs://localhost:8000</value>
            </property>
          </configuration>
          EOF          
        SHELL

      end
```

Comment: The terminating "EOF" must be the **only characters on the line**. No leading/trailing whitespace is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days age, you only need to delete the tabs/spaces in front of the "EOF".

So simply change

```
    cat >/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml <<EOF
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>fs.default.name</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:8000</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
    EOF
```

to

```
    cat >/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml <<EOF
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>fs.default.name</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:8000</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
  EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline shell for this kind of work. Mount actual files in a shared volume with the VM.

Otherwise, you're fighting both the ruby parser and the shell parser, and will certainly run into issues.

You could also use existing Ansible/Puppet/Chef Hadoop provisioning scripts with Vagrant rather than re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @OneCricketer. Your suggestion helped. I created the xml file separately as `core-site.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>fs.default.name</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:8000</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
```

Then, I created a bash file to create a symbolic link with this command

```
 sudo ln -sf /vagrant/hadoopscripts/core-site.xml /home/vagrant/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
```

Finally, I provisioned the bash which I named 'hadoopconfig.sh' from my Vagrantfile with this command.

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "shellscripts/hadoopconfig.sh"
```

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you should use the FQDN hostname for the hdfs address, not localhost

Comment: @OneCricketeer, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You're using `<value>hdfs://localhost:8000</value>`. This will only work on one VM. If you are trying to create a full Hadoop cluster, then you should use `hdfs://vm1.vagrant:8000`, for example, and then other HDFS clients will communicate with that machine instead of all trying to connect to themselves on localhost .

Comment: And like I said, [existing solutions](https://github.com/markush81/fastdata-cluster) that use Ansible might be better than re-creating your own, unless you really just want to learn Vagrant...